# Why does Julie always sneak into Jamie's room by ladder?

Tags: plot-explanation, 20th-century-women

In ***20th Century Women (2016)***, why does Julie always sneak into Jamie's room by ladder?

[image]

Comment: I'm confused by the question.  Is it 'why is she sneaking in' or specifically 'why a ladder'? She's actually using a tree and scaffolding combo, incidentally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

She's sneaking in because she doesn't want Jamie's mother to know that she occasionally spends the night with him.

As for *how* she gets in...it's scaffolding not a ladder as such although there would be a standard 'ladder' portion of the scaffolding to make it easier to climb.

[image]

[image]